# Shares and Signatures Query

Tags: sql

How many shares and signatures (all time) came from petitions within the following signatures buckets: 1-499, 500-999, 1000+.

Note: a petition CANNOT be shared if it didn’t have signatures

Tables: [image]

Currently have and open to any feedback:

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT t1.petition_id) < 500 THEN '1-499'
    WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT t1.petition_id) >= 500 AND COUNT(DISTINCT t1.petition_id) < 1000 THEN '500-999'
    ELSE '1000+' END AS Signature_Buckets
FROM 
  signatures t1
LEFT JOIN 
  shares t2
ON 
  t1.petition_id ON t2.petition_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The explanation of the case is not fully clear. A few rows of sample data could have helped to clarify border cases. Nevertheless, it seems the following query returns the result you want:

```
select
  bucket,
  count(*) as signatures,
  sum(shares) as total_shares
from (
  select 
    s.petition_id,
    count(h.petition_id) as shares,
    case when count(h.petition_id) < 500 then '1-499'
         when count(h.petition_id) < 1000 then '500-999'
         else '1000+' 
    end as bucket
  from signatures s
  left join shares h on h.petition_id = s.petition_id
  group by s.petition_id
  having count(h.petition_id) > 1
) x
```